# ember-leaflet drag point to latlng

Tags: ember.js, leaflet

on my polygon 'dragend' function i get the new position via (e.target._newPos) that represents the position on my layer.

But when i convert that point as follows:

```
  let containerPoint = layer._map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.target._newPos);
  let latlng = layer._map.containerPointToLatLng(containerPoint);
```

i get some coordinates that's what i want. But when i try to present them on my leaflet map layer an zoomin or out that point jumps on my map so wtf is going on?

```
import PolygonLayer from 'ember-leaflet/components/polygon-layer';
```

.
.
.

```
draggable.on('dragend', (e) => {
    let containerPoint = layer._map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.target._newPos);
    let latlng = layer._map.containerPointToLatLng(containerPoint);
    let dragEnd = this.get('onDragEnd');
    dragEnd(latlng);
  });
```

Comment: Try `latlng = layer.getLatLng()`

Comment: No that's not working

Comment: and `latlng = e.target.getLatLng()` ?

Comment: no it's the same maybe i tell some more

Answer (score 0):

In my template i have a presentation of a map

```
  items: {},
```

i have a item component

```
didRender() {
let layer = this.get('_layer');

let path = layer && layer._path;

if (!path) {
  return;
}


  let draggable = new L.Draggable(path);
  draggable.enable();

  draggable.on('dragend', (e) => {
  let containerPoint =   layer._map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.target._newPos);
  let latlng = layer._map.containerPointToLatLng(containerPoint);
 let dragEnd = this.get('onDragEnd');
dragEnd(latlng);
});
},
```

so onDragEnd i will update the dragged items position with new latlngs but after my update the item is jumping on map